# SFML errors while compiling C++ project

Tags: c++, sfml

I'm trying to build a game that uses SDL2 (which compiles fine, but I get seg fault when executing the binary file) and SFML (which I can't get to compile successfully).

These are the errors I get:

```
pi@raspberrypi:~/spaceinvaders $ scons --use_sfml
scons: Reading SConscript files ...
scons: done reading SConscript files.
scons: Building targets ...
g++ -o audio/player.o -c -Wextra -I. -DUSE_BOOST_CHRONO -DBOOST_SP_DISABLE_THREADS -DTIXML_USE_STL -O3 -DUSE_SFML -DNDEBUG audio/player.cpp
audio/player.cpp: In member function 'sf::SoundBuffer oci::audio::{anonymous}::Loader::operator()(const string&)':
audio/player.cpp:52:16: error: 'class sf::SoundBuffer' has no member named 'LoadFromMemory'
audio/player.cpp: In constructor 'oci::audio::{anonymous}::ControllerImpl::ControllerImpl(const sf::SoundBuffer&, bool, bool)':
audio/player.cpp:61:24: error: no matching function for call to 'sf::Sound::Sound(const sf::SoundBuffer&, bool&)'
audio/player.cpp:61:24: note: candidates are:
/usr/local/include/SFML/Audio/Sound.hpp:69:5: note: sf::Sound::Sound(const sf::Sound&)
/usr/local/include/SFML/Audio/Sound.hpp:69:5: note:   candidate expects 1 argument, 2 provided
/usr/local/include/SFML/Audio/Sound.hpp:61:14: note: sf::Sound::Sound(const sf::SoundBuffer&)
/usr/local/include/SFML/Audio/Sound.hpp:61:14: note:   candidate expects 1 argument, 2 provided
/usr/local/include/SFML/Audio/Sound.hpp:53:5: note: sf::Sound::Sound()
/usr/local/include/SFML/Audio/Sound.hpp:53:5: note:   candidate expects 0 arguments, 2 provided
audio/player.cpp:64:20: error: 'class sf::Sound' has no member named 'Play'
audio/player.cpp: In member function 'virtual bool oci::audio::{anonymous}::ControllerImpl::IsPlaying() const':
audio/player.cpp:68:23: error: 'const class sf::Sound' has no member named 'GetStatus'
audio/player.cpp: At global scope:
audio/player.cpp:77:1: error: 'shared_ptr' in namespace 'std' does not name a type
scons: *** [audio/player.o] Error 1
scons: building terminated because of errors.
```

The code has been updated last time in 2015, so I assume it is using some older SFML version (which i don't know) and in the latest version some functions have been changed and the compatibility broke. I can't test older versions because there is only one version available for RPi3 (2.4) .

audio/player.cpp file:

```
#include "player.h"

#ifdef USE_SFML
#   include <SFML/Audio/Sound.hpp>
#   include <SFML/Audio/SoundBuffer.hpp>
#else
#   include <SDL2/SDL_mixer.h>
#endif

#include <portability/cpp11.h>
#include <resources/loader.h>
#include <stdexcept>
#include <utils/cache.h>

namespace oci {
namespace audio {

#ifdef USE_SFML

namespace {

class Loader {
public:
    sf::SoundBuffer operator()(const std::string& name) {
        std::vector<char> data =
            resources::ResourcesLoader::Instance().GetData("sfx/" + name);
        if(data.empty())
            throw std::logic_error("Sound resource \"sfx/" + name +
                                   "\" is empty");
        sf::SoundBuffer sb;
        if(!sb.LoadFromMemory(&data[0], data.size()))
            throw std::logic_error("Cannot load sound \"" + name + "\"");
        return sb;
    }
};

class ControllerImpl : public Controller {
public:
    ControllerImpl(const sf::SoundBuffer& sb, bool autoplay, bool loop) :
        mSound(sb, loop)
    {
        if(autoplay)
            mSound.Play();
    }

    virtual bool IsPlaying() const override {
        return mSound.GetStatus() == sf::Sound::Playing;
    }

private:
    sf::Sound mSound;
};

} // namespace

std::shared_ptr<Controller> Play(const std::string& name, bool autoplay,
                                 bool loop) {
    static Cache<sf::SoundBuffer, Loader> cache;
    const sf::SoundBuffer& sb = cache.Get(name);
    return std::make_shared<ControllerImpl>(sb, autoplay, loop);
}

#else

// SDL audio code, not needed

#endif

} // namespace audio
} // namespace oci
```

Comment: The errors are quite clear; sf::Sound only takes one argument in its constructor.

Comment: You're also using the wrong casing, i.e. `sf::SoundBuffer::loadFromMemory()`, **not** `sf::SoundBuffer::LoadFromMemory()`